# Parent Child Relation in same Table, Get all rows and if child rows are there get it with parent history?

Tags: sql, sql-server

ID and ParentID relation is in the same tabel. The actual Sql tabel and the expected result are in the image:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty simple output, but you would need to use a recursive Common Table Expression

See here the documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I treid with the following Query but not giving me expected Results: </br>USE [Datbasename]
GO
 
WITH getAll(ID, t_s_Name)  
AS (SELECT Name + ' >> ' + Name, 1
    FROM CustTabel AS c  
    WHERE c.ParentID IS NULL  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT ce.Name + ' >> ' + ce.Name , 2
    FROM CustTabel AS ce  
    )  
SELECT ID, Name
FROM CustTabel  ;

Comment: That's because you forgot to include in the second part of the UNION the autojoin (which define the recursivity) between your CTE getAll and CustTabel on CustTabel.ID = getAll.ParentID